# Can file names be changed on uploading with cffile?

Tags: file-upload, coldfusion, upload, cfml

I am currently trying to create a page where bands can upload their own logos onto the site for use where it is needed. Currently, I have created something which allows a user to upload/delete a logo to the allocated directory. But what I want to do is rather than create a band_logo field, have it so the band logo file name becomes the band's id in the database. With this being unique it means I don't have the long-winded process of creating a field to save their logo name. I know there is a `cffile action="rename"` option but that is a more long-winded process of doing things.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if you provide the file name in the `destination` it will rename the file on upload.

```
<cffile action="upload" destination="/path/to/some/directory/#session.bandName#.jpg" ... />
```

See [Renaming Files As They Are Uploaded (how CFFILE actually works)](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/07/renaming_files.html)

BTW, searching google for "[name file on cffile upload](https://www.google.com/search?q=name%20file%20on%20cffile%20upload&aq=f&oq=name%20file%20on%20cffile%20upload&aqs=chrome.0.57j60j61j62l2j60.5286&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)" found that article...

However, you still may want to use

```
<cffile action = "upload" ...>
 then 
<cffile action = "rename" ...>
```

Because unless you snag the file extension on the client side and pass it on to the server, hard coding the file extension could cause problems if they don't upload a `.jpg` or whatever extension you designate. It isn't that much code or overhead and it's safer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfif #ServerFileExt# EQ 'jpg'>
<cffile action="upload" destination="/path/to/some/directory/#session.bandName#.jpg" />

<cffile action="rename"
source="path/to/some/directory/#session.bandName#.jpg"
destination="path/to/some/directory/#getData.bandsID#.jpg">

<cfelse>

   <cflocation addtoken="no" url="back to form upload page"> 

 </cfif>
```